# How to dynamically add LinearLayout on Android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have an array of length n, I now need to create n number of LinearLayouts and add different stuffs on each of them.
How can it be done dynamically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
LinearLayout lLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
parentWidget.addView(lLayout);
```

Comment: And somewhere in there you assign all of its properties (assuming you need something other than defaults).

Comment: You also can set LayoutParams for child LinearLayout. lLayout.setLayoutPatams(layoutParams),

Comment: @ihrupin how to get parentWidget? I'm inside an onCreate method of a class which inherits Activity class and view is setContentView(R.layout.someLayout)

Comment: LineatLayout parentWidget = new LinearLayout(context); setContentView(parentWidget); Thats all :)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to create a layout in xml and inflate it using

`LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_linear_layout);`

You may also want to `setId()` your added views so you can access them easily later on.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it using RelativeLayout which I found a little easier to work with. Yes of-course like the guys pointed out above I used `setId()`. Here is the code I implemented:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

    //Parent RelativeLayout
    parentLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    parentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    parentLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    sv.addView(parentLayout);

    final String[] comList = getCommunication();
    int listLength=0;
    try{
    listLength= comList.length/3;
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);System.exit(0);}

    childLayout= new RelativeLayout[listLength] ;
    TextView[] tvName  = new TextView[listLength];
    TextView[] tvDate  =new TextView[listLength];
    TextView[] tvMsg =new TextView[listLength];

    for(int i =0;i<listLength;i++){
        try{

        childLayout[i] = new RelativeLayout(this);
        childLayout[i].setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 75);
        if(i==0){params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);}
        else{params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,i);}
        childLayout[i].setId(i+1);
        childLayout[i].setClickable(true);
        childLayout[i].setLayoutParams(params);
        childLayout[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                //Create the intent
                  Intent i = new Intent("ACTIIVTY");
                   startActivity(i);
            }       
        });

        tvName[i] = new TextView(this);
        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        tvName[i].setLayoutParams(params);
        childLayout[i].addView(tvName[i]);
        if(comList[i*3].length()>24){
            String name = comList[i*3].substring(0,24)+"...";
            tvName[i].setText(name);
        }else{
            tvName[i].setText(comList[i*3]);
        }
        tvName[i].setId(listLength+1+i);
        tvName[i].setTextSize(12);
        tvName[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        tvDate[i] = new TextView(this);
        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        tvDate[i].setLayoutParams(params);
        childLayout[i].addView(tvDate[i]);
        tvDate[i].setTextSize(11);
        tvDate[i].setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        tvDate[i].setText(comList[i*3+1]);


        tvMsg[i] = new TextView(this);
        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, listLength+1+i);
        tvMsg[i].setLayoutParams(params);
        childLayout[i].addView(tvMsg[i]);
        tvMsg[i].setTextSize(11);
        tvMsg[i].setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        if(comList[i*3+2].length()>96){
            String msg = comList[i*3+2].substring(0,96)+"...";
            tvMsg[i].setText(msg);
        }else{
            tvMsg[i].setText(comList[i*3+2]);
        }

        parentLayout.addView(childLayout[i]);

        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Errrorrrrr");}
    }

    setContentView(sv);
}
```