# App crashing while adding view at run time

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

The code for the adding the view at run time is as follows:
contactActivity.java:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_details);

        mPhoneList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contact_phone_list);

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact_details_item, mPhoneList,false);
        mItemLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_label);
        mItemValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_value);



        //mContactItem = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contact_item);

        mItemLabel.setText("home");  //NULL POINTER EXCEPTION HERE
        mItemValue.setText("999999999999");

        mPhoneList.addView(view);

        mItemLabel.setText("work");
        mItemValue.setText("999gggggggggg");
        mPhoneList.addView(view);   


    }
```

contact_phone_list is in activity_contact_details.xml:

```
some code...
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/contact_phone_list"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/silver"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="16dp" >

            </LinearLayout>
some more code...
```

contact_details_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contact_item"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/contact_item_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/contact_item_value"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

logcat:

```
09-18 19:18:22.359: E/AndroidRuntime(28218):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-18 19:18:22.359: E/AndroidRuntime(28218): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
09-18 19:18:22.359: E/AndroidRuntime(28218):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3378)
09-18 19:18:22.359: E/AndroidRuntime(28218):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3249)
09-18 19:18:22.359: E/AndroidRuntime(28218):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3194)
09-18 19:18:22.359: E/AndroidRuntime(28218):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3170)
09-18 19:18:22.359: E/AndroidRuntime(28218):    at com.glad2.ui.ContactDetailsActivity.onCreate(ContactDetailsActivity.java:51)
09-18 19:18:22.359: E/AndroidRuntime(28218):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-18 19:18:22.359: E/AndroidRuntime(28218):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-18 19:18:22.359: E/AndroidRuntime(28218):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
09-18 19:18:22.359: E/AndroidRuntime(28218):    ... 11 more
```

Could someone please help me understand why the crash is coming?

MODIFIED CODE (Now i am getting a blank screen with no data):

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_details);

        mPhoneList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contact_phone_list);
        mEmailList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contact_email_list);

        for (int i=0; i<5;i++){
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact_details_item, mPhoneList,false);
            mItemLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_label);
            mItemValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_value);


            //mContactItem = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contact_item);
            String t[] = new String[] {"abc", "def", "df", "sd", "kg", "lk"}; 
            mItemLabel.setText(t[i]);
            mItemValue.setText(String.valueOf(i));

            mPhoneList.addView(view);

        }
```

Thanks and regards, 
Sunny

Comment: line 51 is mPhoneList.addView(view);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change these lines

```
mItemLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_item_label);
mItemValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_item_value);
```

to

```
mItemLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_label);
mItemValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_value);
```

The way it is currently written, you are looking in the `activity_contact_details.xml` for these `TextView`s but you need to be looking in the `contact_details_item.xml` for the `id`s since that's where they live.

If this doesn't solve your problem then please post the logcat.

**Edit**

Have "home" and "work" `LinearLayout`s in your xml wrapped in a root `LinearLayout` then these will both be in your `view` and only add `view` to `mPhoneList` once. You can later add `LinearLayout`s dynamically if you will have an undetermined amount of "items" (eg. mobile, work2, etc...)

Ex.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/contact_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/homeLL
       // add other properties, use default horizontal orientation>
      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/contact_item_label"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.3"
          android:textColor="@color/orange"
          android:gravity="right"/>

      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/contact_item_value"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.7"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:gravity="left"/>
     </LinearLayout
     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/workLL
        // add other properties>
       //add your TextViews as in your first LL
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Dynamically create Views**

[Create LinearLayout Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098340/how-to-dynamically-add-linearlayout-on-android)

[Add TextViews to LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918320/dynamically-add-textviews-to-a-linearlayout)

Comment: thanks for the explanation also. now i am getting the following exception. i have updated the main question with the logcat

Comment: You are calling `mPhoneList.addView(view);` twice so after the first time it already has a parent. A `View` may have only one direct parent. Remove one of these calls

Comment: but i want to add a list of items. phone numbers and labels. so how would i do that then

Comment: Create different `TextView`s for each and add them to `View` or whatever `layout`. Or multiple `LinearLayout`s but you can't reuse the same one like that. Then just add `View` once.

Comment: See my edit. I hope that helps...I gave more than I was going to but feel free to ask if you don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. but i do have a liner layout (contact_details_item). So i was hoping to add each item using this linearlayout. how would that work? i mean how would i dynamically add those multiple linearlayouts. thanks. i actually dont want to hardcode anything in the xml. show it based on wht i receive as input

Comment: So, depending on your criteria you would create a new `LinearLayout` with however many `TextView`s you need then add each of those to a root `LinearLayout` like `view` and add that to `mPhoneList` as you are doing.

Comment: I have added a couple links to dynamically create `View`s. I hope that helps. This should get you started and I don't want to write all of the code. But give that a try and there are plenty of examples on SO and The Google if you get stuck.

Comment: thanks a lot. i tried out something and i am getting a blank screen. could you please have a look?

Comment: @Sunny I don't know if this is your problem but `LinearLayout height` in `contact_details_item.xml` should probably be `wrap_content` so you have room for the others

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contact_details_item, mPhoneList,false);
    mItemLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_label);
    mItemValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_value);
```

You should search for `contact_item_label` and `contact_item_value` in your inflated view. Not in the content layout of activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should put :

```
   mItemLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_label);
    mItemValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_value);
```

instead of :

```
 mItemLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_item_label);
    mItemValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_item_value);
```

and it should work correctly